# Can I identify application distributive?

Tags: android, security, architecture, mobile

I'm creating some public mobile application. Then before release I want to make some beta testing inside my company. Everyone who get distib must sign a non-disclosure agreement (NDA). But what if there would be a leak? How I would find a spy?

Can I subscribe somehow each instance to exactly find the traitor ?

Answer (score 2):

> "Can I subscribe somehow each instance to exactly find the traitor ?"

Firstly if you are worried about the people leaking your application simple answer is **DON'T** give it to them!

The only way to prevent them sharing the app is to lock it down to a IMEI or IMSI number.

Another thing is you can compile a different version for EACH beta tester and assign each compile a unique code and display that some where in the app. that way if you find the app leaked any where you can track it down to the person that gave it out.

Also note that all these methods are pretty reverse engineerable so if you are worried about your app leaking the only answer is

"Get better/more trustworthy beta testers"